# keep only the images in tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to create a AutoEncoder using tensorflow datasets as inputs and the outputs.
I loaded the `tf_flowers` dataset using `tensorflow dataset.`

```
splits = ["train[:80%]", "train[80%:90%]", "train[90%:100%]"]`
(ds_train, ds_validation, ds_test), info = tfds.load(name="tf_flowers", with_info=True, split=splits, as_supervised=False)
```

The data has loaded perfectly as expected.
Now what i want do is modify my datasets so that i have only the images i.e, my files and my labels should both be my images.
How can I modify my code to achieve this ?